# How to preserve the state of each list object in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a web-socket that sends images with some data and than I display them inside `AnimatedList`. The problem is that every new data comes in, it reload every single item the list which reloads every image. Also because image is from base64 converted, it can't be cashed.

Is there any way to preserve the state of each object in `AnimatedList` so that when new item is added, it doesn't reload all other objects/images in the list.

`AnimatedList` sample:

```dart
AnimatedList(
  key: node.validListKey,
  controller: widget.scrollController,
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 0, 10),
  initialItemCount: node.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: CurvedAnimation(
          parent: animation,
          curve: Interval(0, 0.2, curve: Curves.ease)),
      child: SizeTransition(
        sizeFactor:
            CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.ease),
        child: DataContainer(data[index])
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Base decode sample:

```dart
child: AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
  child: ExtendedImage.memory(
    base64.decode(data.base),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    loadStateChanged: (state) {
      if (state.extendedImageLoadState ==
          LoadState.completed) {
        return ExtendedRawImage(
          image: state.extendedImageInfo?.image,
        );
      }
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  ),
),
```

**UPDATE#1**
It seems that the problem is about how I insert items in the list. Because I insert new items at start of the list, for some reason it calls init state only for the last element, but not the recently added one. When I insert at the end of the list, problem is solved. Is there any way how I could force to call init state for the recently added item instead of the last?

Insert item example:

```dart
array.add(data);
array.insert(0, data);
if (key.currentState != null)
  key.currentState.insertItem(0, duration: _insertDuation);
```

**UPDATE#2**
So I was able to fix the first problem that my images was reloading by wrapping `AnimatedList` inside `SingleChildScrollView`, adding `reverse: true`, `shrinkWrap: true` and by adding `decode` inside `initState` method.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child : ListView.builer(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    reverse: true,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      ...
    },
  )
);
```

But now the problem is with `remove` method. When I try to remove item from the list, base widget content stays the same, but image changes by one index. I have tried adding unique key for each widget, but that forces to reload each image when data has been added.

```dart
_data.removeAt(0);
if (_validListKey.currentState != null)
  _validListKey.currentState.removeItem(
      0, (context, animation) => Container(),
      duration: Duration.zero);
```

Comment: It's likely your `node.validListKey` that changes. `AnimatedList` does not destroy the state of your list items

Comment: @RémiRousselet I use `Provider` package to manage my states and key for `AnimatedList` (`final NodeHelper node = Provider.of<NodeHelper>(context, listen: false);`). Can that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the `base64.decode(data.base)` in your `initState` function (or an async function that was triggered in `initState`) and cache the results.

Your build function should not trigger this decoding, or should not run any code with a side effect. Right now at every build you are doing a decode and giving a different `Uint8List` instance to `ExtendedImage`. If `ExtendedImage` is implemented correctly, it should not do any UI changes when it's given the same reference in a new `build()` call.

Comment: The problem is that in `initState` I'm getting only the first value all the time until it is off the screen. Because of that, all the images is the same. Maybe the problem is with something else like `Keys`...